# Dual-Boot Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04: How to boot 18.04?

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, 18.04, uefi

I installed ubuntu 18.04 alongside 16.04 on the same SSD. Now when I boot the machine I expected to be given the choice which ubuntu to boot, but nothing happened. Now my system tells me to press F12 to get into boot menu, but also there I don't see an option to boot 18.04 or anything like that. When I press ESC key during start up to get to GRUB menu there are also only two options: "ubuntu" and "system setup". However when I booted into 16.04 I can see my ubuntu 18.04 partition and I can access it. So how can I boot it?

Comment: Did you tried boot-repair to fix the problem?
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

This software can fix your problem. Try to use that.

Comment: You should get to the Grub boot menu by holding the Shift key. It is not the same as the BIOS boot menu.

Comment: @mikewhatever I already got to grub menu by pressing escape, not shift. And I am sure, it was the grub menu not the BIOS boot menu. But my boot option was not listed there.

Comment: Are both installs in same boot mode? Both UEFI or both BIOS? have you run `sudo update-grub` ?

Comment: @oldfred I now decided to abandon 16.04. I formated the harddrive and reinstalled 18.04. For some reason I could still not boot 18.04. Don't know what I was doing wrong. However, I then reset BIOS to default, formatted the harddrive again and reinstalled ubuntu for a third time and now it's finally working. Really don't know what was going on there. But I think I'll delete this question now, since my problem is gone.